# Retrieval of passport number on expired British passport

Tags: passports

My partner has been asked to submit passport details for a British passport he held in 1998 to support a British citizenship application for his son. He has been unable to locate the expired passport that he used at the time and so we're wondering if there is a way of accessing, at the very least, the passport number.

We're assuming this record might be held with a UK Visa/Immigration Office? Would anyone know if this is possible, and if so, how to go about getting such information? Many thanks.

Comment: You existing passport/passport application may contain details of your previous passport.

Comment: You might find the information at https://www.gov.uk/government/organisations/home-office/about/personal-information-charter#how-to-ask-for-your-data useful. Note that it's the Passport Office which issues British passports.